# Using a SQLConnection object from entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I have a scenario where an external library needs to be called within the scope of a transaction derived from an entity framework connection.

The external library writes messages to a table in the database that's defined by the ef connection.
The signature of the library is something like:`IMessageWriter GetMessageWriter(SqlConnection sqlConnectionObject)`

In use, it looks like:

```
 using (var db = DBContextFactory.CreateDatabaseConnection())
        {
            var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
            //Do some stuff        

            SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection) (db.Database.Connection);
            var msgWriter = _obf.GetMessageWriter(connection);
            msgWriter.WriteToOutbox(record);
            transaction.Commit();

        }
```

The problem is, inside the library, when it tries accessing the database, it throws the error: 
"Prepare requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized."

Commenting out the transaction lines, results in the error:
Prepare requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Does anyone know how to take the EF connection, with the transaction, and get a SQL connection that will execute with the transaction? I'd like to avoid separate connections & transaction scopes, if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038357/executereader-requires-command-to-have-transaction-when-connection-assigned-to-c It looks like the library uses `SqlCommand` without setting the `SqlCommand.Transaction`

Comment: Thank-you. I was able to set the transaction on the command object by doing the following:  'command.Transaction = (SqlTransaction) transaction.UnderlyingTransaction;'