# ExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We get a strange exception when passing a transaction to EF:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: ExecuteReader requires the command to have a
>   transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a
>   pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command
>   has not been initialized.

```
this.DbContext = this.DbContextFactory.CreateContext<TContext>(connection);
this.DbContext.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
```

This exception is caught by EF because it is shown only when 'Break when thrown'  is on. Is it expected behavior or are we doing something potentially wrong?

Here is how call stack looks like:

```
System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(string method, bool async)
System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior runBehavior, bool returnStream, string method, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<object> completion, int timeout, out System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool asyncWrite)
System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior runBehavior, bool returnStream, string method)
System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, string method)
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.IDbCommandInterceptor>.Dispatch<System.Data.Common.DbCommand, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader>, System.Data.Common.DbDataReader>(System.Data.Common.DbCommand target, System.Func<System.Data.Common.DbCommand, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader>, System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> operation, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext, System.Action<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.IDbCommandInterceptor, System.Data.Common.DbCommand, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader>> executing, System.Action<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.IDbCommandInterceptor, System.Data.Common.DbCommand, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader>> executed)
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll!System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlVersionUtils.GetServerType(System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection)
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll!System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.QueryForManifestToken(System.Data.Common.DbConnection conn)
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll!System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken.AnonymousMethod__9(System.Data.Common.DbConnection conn)
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll!System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection.AnonymousMethod__32()
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll!System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute.AnonymousMethod__0()
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll!System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute<object>(System.Func<object> operation)
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll!System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection)
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection)
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices providerServices, System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection)
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<System.Tuple<System.Type, string, string>, string>.GetOrAdd(System.Tuple<System.Type, string, string> key, System.Func<System.Tuple<System.Type, string, string>, string> valueFactory)
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection, out System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(System.Data.Common.DbConnection providerConnection)
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext internalContext)
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy<System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel>.GetValue(System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext input)
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.GetObjectContextWithoutDatabaseInitialization()
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Database.UseTransaction(System.Data.Common.DbTransaction transaction)
```

Transaction is created within `Open` method of the session:

```
public virtual void Open(IsolationLevel isolation, string user)
{
    ValidateState(false);

    this.m_user = user;
    this.m_connection = this.m_database.CreateConnection();
    this.m_connection.Open();
    if (IsolationLevel.Unspecified != isolation)
    {
        this.m_transaction = this.m_connection.BeginTransaction(isolation);
    }
}
```

Then this method is overreiden in the class which supports EF:

```
public override void Open(System.Data.IsolationLevel isolation, string user)
{
    if (isolation == System.Data.IsolationLevel.Unspecified)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Isolation level 'Unspecified' is not supported");
    }
    base.Open(isolation, user);
    this.DbContext = this.DbContextFactory.CreateContext<TContext>(this.Connection);
    this.DbContext.Database.UseTransaction(this.Transaction);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a segment of custom code from which you are invoking EF? Especially pay attention to any enclosing `using` block from within which you are querying the database.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat The exception is thrown inside this.DbContext.Database.UseTransaction(transaction); We are not querying database at that moment. Just instantiating context inside our 'session' object.

Comment: But what is the `transaction` object you are passing? Where is it coming from?

Comment: @ZoranHorvat I've added some code to my question (at the bottom).

Comment: I'm out of ideas. The problem occurs when EF is building the model, and I suspect from the call stack that it is checking whether the DB model has changed compared to code (I might be wrong on that). If someone has used the transaction and closed it before that call, I would rather expect an exception that complains about *state* of the transaction, not that it's not set. When you solve the problem, please post the solution here, I'm interested to see it.

Comment: P.S. Maybe you've just stumbled upon an EF bug here. It draws my attention that you're opening transaction before really doing anything with the DbContext. Is there a way for you to build the model before calling UseTransaction? You can pass compiled model to DbContext, and only after that call UseTransaction. That could work around this problem.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat I have the same reasoning, but what do you meen under 'passing compiled model'? Went for googling and fount this [article](https://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/3-steps-for-fast-entityframework-6.1-code-first-startup-performance/)

Comment: You can refer to this article, which tells how to compile the model before creating DbContext instance: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8bb50366-e64a-4c7f-a8e8-ed604a3da653/how-to-force-dbcontext-onmodelcreating-triggered-before-my-custom-code?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: I mean, you shouldn't need a transaction to build the model - that is what doesn't fit naturally in your code in my opinion.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat Yes, I understood you. Will play with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExecuteReader requires command to have transaction when connection assigned to command is in pending local trans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038357/executereader-requires-command-to-have-transaction-when-connection-assigned-to-c)

Answer (score 4):

During its initialization, `DdContext` will determine the version of SQL Server. This process will attempt to connect to the underlying server and query `select cast (serverproperty ('EngineEdition') as int)` using the provided connection, or in the absence of that, creating a new one from the configured connectionstring.

This will happen only once, after its first initialization.

Therefore, if your first use of `DbContext` in your application life cycle is from within a transaction, this will cause `DbContext` to try to use this connection and result in the observed error.

If you assure a first non-transactional call to `DbContext` (`DbContext` construction and usage for querying), you will avoid this behavior.

```
    private static object _syncRoot = new object();
    private static bool _Initialized = false;

    private MyDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
    }

    private MyDbContext(DbTransaction dbTransaction) : base(dbTransaction.Connection, false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
        Database.UseTransaction(dbTransaction);
    }

    public static MyDbContext Factory()
    {
        return new MyDbContext(Tools.GetDefaultConnectionString());
    }

    public static MyDbContext Factory(DbTransaction dbTransaction)
    {
        if(_Initialized==false)
        {
            lock(_syncRoot)
            {
                if(_Initialized==false)
                {
                    using (MyDbContext tempDbContext = new MyDbContext(dbTransaction.Connection.ConnectionString))
                    using (System.Data.Common.DbTransaction temptransaction = tempDbContext.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        var mySampleData = tempDbContext.OneRowTable.AsNoTracking().ToList();
                        temptransaction.Commit();
                        _Initialized = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        MyDbContext finalContext = new MyDbContext(dbTransaction);
        return finalContext;
    }
```

This is a solution for a scenario where you can not or do not want to use a `TransactionScope` in your software.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears on *first* access to to the underling ObjectContext (attempting to set the transaction accesses the underlying context). Using a TransactionScope is fine; this issue is when using a connection that *already* has a local transaction associated with it.

While a bit ugly, and approach such as the follow does work around this issue. Specific implementation details such as determining `notCreateYet` are left as an exercise.

```
if (notCreatedYet)
{
    // Create a second session/connection to not touch the incoming connection.
    // Using a TransactionScope works and proper enlistment is done.
    // Attempts to open a manual transaction prior to creation will fail.
    using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
    using (var initConn = new SqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        initConn.Open();
        var tempContext = this.DbContextFactory.CreateContext<TContext>(connection);
        // Touch the object context.
        if (tempContext is IObjectContextAdapter contextAdapter)
        {
            _ = contextAdapter.ObjectContext;
        }
    }
}

// Then later on this is fine.
this.DbContext = this.DbContextFactory.CreateContext<TContext>(connection);
this.DbContext.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
```