# C# Insert to Database

Tags: c#, database

```
List<string> tableExtractDB = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < validationResultObj.siTableExtract.Count; i++)
{
    List<string> tableExtract = new List<string>();
    for (int j = 0; j < validationResultObj.siTableExtract[i].Count; j++)
    {
        tableExtract.Add(validationResultObj.siTableExtract[i][j].ToString());
    }
    tableExtractDB = CheckDatabase(tableExtract, createdBy);


    foreach (string insertdb in tableExtractDB)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(insertdb);
        command = new SqlCommand(insertdb, geologyConnection);  
        command.ExecuteReader();
    
        // command.CommandText = insertdb;
        // command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        // command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I am quite new to c# to SQL command.

But I keep getting this error:

> ExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized

What should I do? or what are the change need to be made?

I wanted to insert to database. The SQL statement will get from `tableExtractDB`

Example:

```
INSERT INTO SI.SAMP (HOLE_ID, SAMP_TOP, SAMP_REF, SAMP_TYPE, SAMP_DIA, 
                     SAMP_BASE, SAMP_DESC, PROJ_ID, CreatedBy, CreatedDate) 
VALUES ('Jurong10_BH2', 3.5, 'SPT1', 'SPTLS', 35, 3.95, 
        'Stiff Reddish brown mottled yellowish brown, purple and light grey Slightly fine to coarse grained sandy SILT', 
        'Jurong10', 'tester1', SYSDATETIME())
```

Comment: `geologyConnection` Looks like this connection is used more than one place and some where it is leaving the transaction uncommitted. With this code it not possible to judge what is happening. Did you try creating a new connection here in this method and execute the command using it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ExecuteReader requires command to have transaction when connection assigned to command is in pending local trans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038357/executereader-requires-command-to-have-transaction-when-connection-assigned-to-c)

Comment: @Chetan
**geologyConnection**  is only use that this section. 
I not sure is that the string I getting for the insert statement is not get respond..

Comment: What happened when you used `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`?

Comment: @Chetan

"System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.'"

This is what I get. So I not sure what command should I initialized

Comment: can you share how `geologyConnection` is created? and how do you confirm that it is used only here?

Comment: SqlConnection geologyConnection = null;
geologyConnection = common.GeologyConnection();
geologyConnection.Open();


 command.Connection = geologyConnection;
 command.Transaction = geologyConnection.BeginTransaction();

After that is the method I using above

Comment: The following may be helpful: [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) (see the examples).